# GeoMesa: Polygon zoom scaling in Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, geomesa

I wrote a POLYGON geometry column to my cassandra table, and everything looks fine in the Geoserver admin configuration as far as configuring the data store and layer for the GeoMesa feature. However, when rendered, the polygon scale is extremely small, especially when the map is first rendered in a zoomed-out mode. The zoom scaling is so small on the polygon that it is virtually invisible when the map is first rendered. Is there anything that can be done to adjust the zoom scaling? As you zoom out I believe the image should shrink, but still be visible at some cutoff zoom level.

Images attached.

Thanks.

[image]

Scale 1:24477405

[image]

Scale 1:1529838

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SLDs (styled layer descriptors) to draw the polygon at different zoom levels. See this [gisexchange post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58968/display-points-labels-starting-at-certain-zoom-level) for an example (using points). There are more examples of polygon styling in the [geoserver docs](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/cookbook/).